# Assign Latitude and Longitude in R language

Tags: r

I have one NetCDF file with Lat Lon with the index numbers from 0 to 1200.

when I print head(lat) it shows the index numbers from 
[,1]     [,2]     [,3]     [,4]     [,5] ... to [,1200]
same with head(lon)

I need to assign these index number into lat lon coordinates.

Because I need to extract the grid data (a square grid box), So from that index numbers, I am not able to figure out which index number belongs to lat lon coordinates.

And then I need to do mean of that grid box. So that I can get avg value at every time steps.

In the file summary, only 2 time steps include, but in my original file, the time steps are 365. So I need to avg value of at each time step. 
The summary of the file is given below

File Desktop/test/MAIACTAOT_TIME/maiactaotE.h00v03.20003660525-20003660700.nc (NC_FORMAT_CLASSIC):

```
 3 variables (excluding dimension variables):
    double GridLat_grid1km[XDim_grid1km,YDim_grid1km]   
        projection: Albers Conical Equal_Area
        corners: 32.038387901543
         corners: 34.9985549202943
         corners: 24.5580030404694
         corners: 21.8673735745303
        long_name: latitude
        units: degrees_north
    double GridLon_grid1km[XDim_grid1km,YDim_grid1km]   
        projection: Albers Conical Equal_Area
        corners: 64.23634233372
         corners: 76.8178669755363
         corners: 79.4747290253718
         corners: 68.077149355049
        long_name: longitude
        units: degrees_east
    short Optical_Depth_055_grid1km[XDim_grid1km,YDim_grid1km,time]   
        coordinates: GridLat_grid1km, GridLon_grid1km
        hdfeos_name: Optical_Depth_055
        projection: Albers Conical Equal_Area
        valid_range: -100
         valid_range: 5000
        _FillValue: -28672
        unit: None
        add_offset: 0
        scale_factor: 0.001
        long_name: AOT at 0.55 micron

 3 dimensions:
    time  Size:2   *** is unlimited ***
        units: hours since 2000-01-01 00:00:00
        calendar: standard
    YDim_grid1km  Size:1200
    XDim_grid1km  Size:1200

5 global attributes:
    creation_date: Tue Oct 17 12:37:58 IST 2017
    Conventions: None
    NCL_version: Any version of NCL >= 5.2.0 (4/2010)
    source_file: MAIACTAOT HDF-EOS files
    title: MAIACTAOT HDF-EOS: time dimension added to selected variables
```

Comment: so... where's your code?

Comment: getwd()
ncname <- "Desktop/test/MAIACTAOT_TIME/maiactaotE.h00v03.20003660525-20003660700"
ncfname <- paste(ncname, ".nc", sep = "")
ncin <- nc_open(ncfname)
print(ncin)

dname <-"Optical_Depth_055_grid1km"
dname


time <- ncvar_get(ncin,"time")
time
tunits <- ncatt_get(ncin,"time","units")
nt <- dim(time)
nt


lon <- ncvar_get(ncin, "GridLon_grid1km")
nlon <-dim(lon)
head(lon)
dim(lon)

lat <- ncvar_get(ncin, "GridLat_grid1km")
nlat <-dim(lat)
head(lat)
dim(lat)

print(c(nlon, nlat))

Comment: Please edit your original question with the code and format it properly.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, you are probably looking for the function `ncvar_get` from `ncdf4` R Package.
[This page](http://geog.uoregon.edu/GeogR/topics/netCDF-read-ncdf4.html) is very helpful for netCDF in R.

Try this:

```
lat <- ncvar_get(your_netcdf, "GridLat_grid1km")
long <- ncvar_get(your_netcdf, "GridLon_grid1km")
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: I also did that, But when I do print(lat) ........then It shows [,1] [1,2] up to [,1200]...... but not as degree coordinates.

Comment: @user3473499 It is because your files seems to be already gridded. Is your data available?

Comment: the data is not available online. So, how can i upload my data? please let me know

Comment: @user3473499 You can use any cloud app like Dropbox or SkyDrive.

Comment: okay, but you are right that the data is in grid format. the lat dimension is in matrix form between 1200, 1200 same as lon dimension. The values of lat and lon are is in degree coordinates. Now I have converted my variable (AOT) into matrix form which is between 1200, 1200. So how can I extract the AOT data on particular lat lon coordinates? e.g. if i want to extract 23N, 68E then ?

Comment: @user3473499 I know that you've probably this, but just in case... Have you tried using `[ , ]` (like on ordinary `matrix` objects)?

Comment: I have assigned my data in 3 column header V1,V2,V3 as lat,lon,variable using melt(lat) -> lat3 as with lon and  var. Now I have row of 1200*1200 = 1440000. the class is data.fame